# docker returned a non-zero code: 100 while installing windscribe vpn on an ubuntu container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, vpn

I'm trying to install windscribe vpn on a docker container but I get this output from the command `docker-compose build` and other similar questions don't seem to relate

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resolvconf
 windscribe-cli
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y windscribe-cli' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

this is the code from my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
#install windscribe
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key FDC247B7
RUN echo 'deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/windscribe-repo.list
RUN apt install --reinstall ca-certificates -y
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y windscribe-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

> deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic main

It looks you want to add a `bionic`(AKA. ubuntu18.04) source, while your base image `ubuntu:latest` is `focal`(AKA. ubuntu20.04):

```
$ docker run --rm ubuntu:latest cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

Such kinds of debian package mismatch may results in such kinds of errors, so change `FROM ubuntu:latest` to `FROM ubuntu:18.04` may have good luck.